# show that speed of particle remains constant

Tags: calculus

This is the question:

[image]

Im not sure what to do with this problem.

Comment: Consider the square of the speed, that is $\lVert \vec{v}\rVert^2$. Differentiate that.

Answer (score 1):

Take the dot product of both sides with $\vec{v}$.  Note that

$$\vec{v} \cdot \frac{d}{dt}\vec{v} = \frac12 \frac{d}{dt}(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}) $$

and

$$\vec{v} \cdot (\vec{v} \times \vec{B})=0$$